# Оптимизация mysql запроса

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT `artist`.*, (
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM `audio` 
  WHERE `audio`.`artist` = `artist`.`name`
) as `track` 
  FROM `artist` 
  WHERE `name` REGEXP "^' . ($ch == '#' ? '[0-9]' : $ch) . '" 
  ORDER BY `name` asc
```

Как можно оптимизировать данный запрос?

В таблице `audio` 150к строк

В таблице `artist` 10к строк

Поле `name` в таблице `artist` имеет тип `text` и полнотекстовый индекс
Поле `artist` в таблице `audio` имеет тип `text` и также содержит полнотекстовый индекс

Запрос длится примерно 10 сек.

P.S. как тут сделать перевод строки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Уберите `полнотекстовый индекс`
2. Добавьте идентифицирующие поля ( числовые ) для обеих таблиц ( audio.id, artist.id )
3. Сделайте внешний ключ ( foreign key ) поля audio.artist на artist.id (если FK нет - то просто индекс)

ИМХО: Избегайте связи по текстовым полям - это долго и почти всегда неуместно

UPD: Если у каких-то audio нет artist - пишите в поле Null...

Comment: По поводу "Избегайте связи по текстовым полям" - солидарен на 100%.

Comment: Расскажите про `foreign key` поподробнее.

Comment: Просто вбейте в гугл "sql foreign key"...

Comment: @AlexWindHope, исходя из того, что ТС использует полнотекстовые индексы, можно сделать вывод, что у него используется движек MyISAM. Следовательно, внешние ключи не доступны.

Comment: Никто не мешает сделать ALTER TABLE ;D

Comment: Да MyISAM.

Comment: Предложил FK как подходящий (структурно/логически) вариант, ничего не мешает использовать обычный индекс.

Answer (score 1):

- Добавьте для обоих таблицы `artist` поле `id int autoincrement` и сделайте его первичным ключем.
- Для таблицы `audio` добавьте поле `artist_id`, создайте для него обычный BTREE индекс и в дальнейшем связывайте таблицы по этим полям.
- Добавьте BTREE индекс для artist.name
- С учетом предыдущих пунктов запрос можно оптимизировать примерно сл. образом:

  ```
  SELECT ar.name, count(au.id)
  FROM artist AS ar
  LEFT JOIN audio AS au ON ar.id = au.artist_id
  WHERE ar.name REGEXP "^' . ($ch == '#' ? '[0-9]' : $ch) . '"
  GROUP BY ar.name
  ORDER BY ar.name ASC
  ```

Такой запрос будет выполнятся очень быстро.

Comment: В таблицах естественно есть id (AT) с первичным ключом. 
Не пойму как работает GROUP BY
И добавить в таблицу audio artist_id не получится, так как не все строки audio имеют своего artist который есть в таблице artist.

Жесть написал, думаю поймете.

Comment: Такой запрос не будет работать быстрее ( если получать artist.* а не усекать )....

Comment: > И добавить в таблицу audio artist_id не получится, так как не все строки audio имеют своего artist который есть в таблице artist.

В этом случае проставляйте в это поле null. Или вы имеете ввиду, что поле artist.name у вас не уникальное?

> Такой запрос не будет работать быстрее ( если получать artist.* а не усекать )

Именно замена подзапроса на join возможно и не даст большого ускорения. Нужно смотреть explsin.

Основное ускорение даст добавление индекса BTREE для artist.name (т.к. по этому полю идет сортировка, то скорее всего именно этот индекс и будет использоваться) и и поле artist_id